# Удалить линию Line2D двойным кликом мышки (Java | JFrame)

Tags: java, swing, графы, jframe, mouse-event

```
public Line2D find_Line(Point2D p)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
    {
        Line2D l = (Line2D) lines.get(i);
        if(l.contains(p))
        {
            return l;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public void remove_Line(Line2D line)
{
    if(line == null)
        return;

    if(line == this.line)
        this.line = null;

    lines.remove(line);

    repaint();
}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getClickCount() >= 2)
        {
            current = find(e.getPoint());
            one_press = false;
            current2 = null;
            if (current != null)
            {
                remove(current);
            }
            else
            {
                line = null;
                line = find_Line(e.getPoint());

                if(line != null)
                {
                    remove_Line(line);
                }
            }
        }
    }

public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if(find(e.getPoint()) == null && find_Line(e.getPoint()) == null)
            setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
        else
            setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR_CURSOR));
    }

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponents(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    for(int i = 0; i < circle.size(); i++)
    {
        g2.setColor(new Color(10, 170 , 133));
        g2.draw((Ellipse2D) circle.get(i));

        g2.setColor(new Color(250 , 110 , 50));
        g2.drawString(iterator.get(i).toString() , (float)((Ellipse2D) circle.get(i)).getCenterX() , (float)((Ellipse2D) circle.get(i)).getCenterY());
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
    {
        g2.setColor(new Color(10, 170 , 133));
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
        g2.draw((Line2D) lines.get(i));
    }
}
```

Добрый день! Хочу удалить нарисованную линию двойным кликом мышки. При навведении на линию, курсор не меняется на крест. Эти линии рисуются между кругами (работа по теории графов). Все линии я храню в ArrayList.

Я находил линию так: смотрел на место клика и проверял вхождение с помощью contains. Я думаю, что лажа именно в contains...
   Могу скинуть весь код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод [Line2D.contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.html#contains(java.awt.geom.Point2D)) всегда возвращает false, т.к. у отрезка нет площади. Метод присутствует чтобы реализовать контракт с `Shape`

> This method is required to implement the Shape interface, but in the case of Line2D objects it always returns false since a line contains no area.

Вместо этого можно считать расстояние от точки до отрезка с помощью [Line2D.ptLineDist](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.html#ptLineDist(java.awt.geom.Point2D)). Если расстояние меньше заданной погрешности, считать точку принадлежащей отрезку.